# How to take set union of all the values in a column of pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

First two rows of a dataframe, `df`:

```
0|50331648|{1,2,3,4,5}|6  
1|50331649|{3,5,7,8}|2
```

After performing the operation, I just need a set that contains   `{1,2,3,4,5,7,8}`.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `"B"` to be the column name under consideration, you could use [`set.union`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#set.union) on the obtained unpacked list:

```
set.union(*df['B'].tolist())
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
```

(Or)

Supply these as a callable function to `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce      # If you're on Py3k
reduce(set.union, df['B'].tolist())
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}
```

***Data:***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[50331648, 50331649],
                       B=[{1,2,3,4,5}, {3,5,7,8}],
                       C=[6,2])
                 )
```

[image]